# handle security popup using vbscript (without QTP/Selenium)

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, wsh

I am automating an application login using vbscript.

I am using the code -

```
Dim objIE
Set objIE = Wscript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate "https://portal url"
```

after this, there is a security pop up which asks for user name and password.

I dont want to disable the pop-up. Rather i want to be able to put user id and password in to it.

I tried handling it through

`NewWindow3` method and
`NewWindow2` method

which MSDN has provided for handling extra windows(This for development rather than for automation I guess) but does not work out.

`objIE.Document.GetElementByID

also does not work out becuse the pop-up does not come under 'Document' object. it comes directly under objIE, but could not find anything to handle it.

Comment: I tried using HWND to get the window handle, but I can only use it using 'Extern.Declare' statement which is QTP supported and beats the purpose. Any one has used pure vbscript to capture window handle? Also tried getting 'MSVBVM60.dll' as given in the link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/gopal_code.aspx but the dll is custom made and only provides two methods 'Find' and 'Kill', using which I cannot type in user id and password.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code for pass credentials to the Windows Authentication dialog. I hope it helps.

```
Dim objIE, objWshShell
Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate "http://url"
Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
With objWshShell
    WScript.Sleep 100
    .SendKeys "myusername" 'Focused by Default - Username
    WScript.Sleep 100
    .SendKeys "{TAB}" 'Skip To Password Field
    WScript.Sleep(100)
    .SendKeys "mypassword" 'Password     
    WScript.Sleep 100
    .SendKeys "{TAB}" 'Skip To "Remember Me" Checkbox
    WScript.Sleep 100
    .SendKeys "{TAB}" 'Skip To Submit Button
    WScript.Sleep 100
    .SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'GO
End With
Set objWshShell = Nothing
Set objIE = Nothing
```